# Visual studio hangs while creating .ipa

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios

​I am trying to create .ipa for my xamarin.iOS project but unfortunately it is hanging while creating a build.Once i select the certificates and provisioning the mouse start showing busy symbol and visual studio stops responding.

Comment: can you share the text from your output window?

Comment: Are you using visual-studio 2010 or visual-studio-2012?

Comment: @Kyle It just hangs and nothing outputs, each time i need to force quit it.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for mac  version 8.5.3(build 13)

Comment: Maybe you can try to remove and reinstall the certificates in your Mac. Also re-add the Apple Account in the Visual-studio.

Comment: I have done that too and if i am uploading the same ipa(after extracting from package content) through xcode(application loader) it is working fine and uploaded directly to itunes but only issue comes in visual studio....not getting any hints why it's happening so......?

Comment: The latest stable visual-studio for mac is 8.3.7.1 on my side, are you sure you are using  8.5.3?